# WCF - Get Current User Identity

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a silverlight application that send calls to a server. The server use WCF service to perform the call. I want to be able to check on the 'AfterReceiveRequest' function if the user who performs the call is the one I expected. if not - I want to abort the operation.

The problem is - I can't get the IIS user name properly.
I tried this properties:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

And

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

They give me the right user name only when I run the application from Visual Studio, and not on the Application Pool. When I run the application on the Application pool I get in both these parameters the value: IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationPool.

The Client and Server are on the same machine, so this doesn't seems like a double-hop.

Can anyone help? I need this to work in both Windows and Basic authentication.

Comment: You need to use Windows Authentication base on my knowledge.When using Windows Authentication you need a windows username.Yo need to handle this operations with Windows Authentication.

Comment: First of all - The values of the above parameters is not correct even when using Windows Authentication. And besides - I don't see any reason not to use Basic Authentication as well...

Answer (score 2):

These identity values come from the authentication method that is used for WCF. You should post your WCF server side and client side configs. To enable Windows Authentication which uses encrypted hand shaking based on Windows authentication, please follow this article with an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-secure-a-service-with-windows-credentials

Once you have this working, you will be able to see the Windows identity here:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity
```

The key is to turn the security mode on at the binding level on the server side.

In code:

```
    var myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
    myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
```

In config:

```
<bindings>  
  <wsHttpBinding>  
   <binding name = "wsHttpBinding_Calculator">  
     <security mode="Message">  
       <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>  
     </security>  
    </binding>  
  </wsHttpBinding>  
</bindings>
```

I don't think the clientCredentialType="Windows" is even necessary because if 
it is not specified, you can still get the windows user identity anyway.

In response to your points about VS vs. IIS - this shouldn't be an issue. What I'd say is going on there is that the IIS service somehow doesn't access to the Active Directory domain. This could be a permissions issue. But, by default IIS should work in the same way as Visual Studio as Visual Studio just uses IIS Express. If IIS is configured with the same username as IIS Express, it should have access to authenticate over the domain in the same way. Note: ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity is not the IIS username. It is the Windows username.

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks.